# KDB: Difference between .Q.hp/.Q.hg and the built in HTTP request. And do either persist/Keep alive?

Tags: http, kdb

Its seems a http get can be performed using either .Q.hg or using the built in HTTP request like

`:http://host:port "string to send as HTTP method etc"
(from https://code.kx.com/q/kb/programming-examples/)

Is there any difference?

And do either persist/keep-alive by default?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using .Q.hg allows you to use a string which is formatted in a way that is consistent with a web-based url request, .e.g for requesting some csv data from a server:

```
t:.Q.hg`$":http://www.website.com/report1/format=csv&cols=sym&cols=price&date=20200630";
/the resulting string contains the data only (no metadata/headers) and can be parsed directly
("SF";1#csv)0:t
```

The GET equivalent is not like a browser url, however it does return the metadata/headers (which in turn makes it messier to parse), e.g.

```
t:(hsym`$"http://www.website.com") "GET /report1/format=csv&cols=sym&cols=price&date=20200630 HTTP/1.1\r\nhost:www.website.com\r\n\r\n";
/result looks like
"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nDate: Fri, 03 Jul 2020 14:46:33 GMT\r\nContent-Type: application/txt\r\nContent-Length: 1345\r\nConnection: keep-alive ...."
/parsed using something like (strip away metadata to get to the data)
("SF";1#csv)0:_[;t]3+first t ss "\n\r\n"
```

The resulting metadata/header shows "Connection: keep-alive" in my example that I've just tested so perhaps that's the default? I'm not 100% on that.

.Q.hg also has the advantage of being compatible with HTTPS and making use of proxies as per the documentation: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qhg-http-get

Answer (score 1):

.Q.hg and .Q.hp have a similar functionality to the example outlined in the link, without having to construct the HTTP requests as strings (these functions will construct the strings for you). The example was perhaps written before the .Q.hg/.Q.hp functions were introduced in v3.4.

I don't think either persist by default assuming they use HTTP 1.0 protocol.